# Xmodmap releases modifier keys when some keys are pressed with the modifier keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xmodmap

My computer is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the Linux kernel 5.0.0-23-generic.

I remap the `Shift_R` key to a `Mode_switch`,

```
clear Shift
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  62 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
add Shift = Shift_L
```

and some `Shift_L-Shift_R-<key>` keys to symbols, for example,

```
keycode  41 = i I I braceleft
keycode  53 = t T T grave
```

Although some of them work well, others do not.

For example, `Shift_L-Shift_R-F` (keycode `41`) prints `{` (correct), while `Shift_L-Shift_R-X` (keycode `53`) prints nothing.

So I ran `xev` and pressed `Shift_L` (keycode `50`), `Shift_R` (keycode `62`), `X` (keycode `53`):

```
$ xev
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3610499, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3611315, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3612803, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x2001, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3612803, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x2000, keycode 62 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

then released in the reverse order:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3614962, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3614962, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3616673, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x2001, keycode 62 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x31c, subw 0x0, time 3617441, (1273,328), root:(1347,399),
    state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`Shift_L` and `Shift_R` are released when `Shift_L-Shift_R-X`?

---

All the changes of `xmodmap` from the default is:

```
clear Shift
keycode  20 = minus question question underscore
keycode  24 = v V V V
keycode  25 = k K K K
keycode  26 = r R R R
keycode  27 = y Y Y Y
keycode  28 = q Q Q Q
keycode  29 = x X X X
keycode  30 = a A A A
keycode  31 = f F F F
keycode  32 = u U U U
keycode  33 = d D D D
keycode  34 = z Z Z Z
keycode  35 = dollar asciicircum asciicircum dollar
keycode  36 = slash Escape Escape slash
keycode  38 = h H H H
keycode  39 = j J J plus
keycode  40 = l L L bracketleft
keycode  41 = i I I braceleft
keycode  42 = semicolon apostrophe apostrophe parenleft
keycode  43 = colon quotedbl quotedbl parenright
keycode  44 = o O O braceright
keycode  45 = s S S bracketright
keycode  46 = e E E asterisk
keycode  47 = g G G G
keycode  48 = b B B B
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde asciitilde grave
keycode  51 = backslash bar bar backslash
keycode  52 = m M M M
keycode  53 = t T T grave
keycode  54 = n N N numbersign
keycode  55 = BackSpace backslash backslash BackSpace
keycode  56 = comma less less equal
keycode  57 = period greater greater minus
keycode  58 = Return underscore underscore Return
keycode  59 = c C C percent
keycode  60 = w W W asciitilde
keycode  61 = p P P P
keycode  62 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
add Shift = Shift_L
```

Well-keys (like `Shift_L-Shift_R-F` becomes `{`) are

- 20, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 56, 57, 61.

Wrong-keys (like `Shift_L-Shift_R-X` releases `Shift_L` and `Shift_R`) are

- 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 52, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60.

How different are these two types of keys?

How can I fix this strange behavior?

Comment: `xmodmap` is just an application to modify the tables in the X server (so it's not "xmodmap" which releases the keys, but the keyboard routines inside the X server), which in turn are a layer on top of xkb. So whatever happens, it probably happens in xkb. So use `setxkbmap -query` to find your keyboard configuration, then have a very close look at the involved files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`. But first use `evdev` to rule out there's anything funny happening on the lower levels (kernel input layer).

Comment: Now I changed the xmodmap config to another (similar) key-mapping, then `Shift_L-Shift_R` works well. But I want to know what caused the problem. I will go through `evdev` and `xkb`. Thanks.